# Google Pub/Sub API - Maximum messages

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I've created a small app which can call the Pub/Sub API via the REST reference. In the API Reference guide, it shows that the request body can have multiple messages, see the example below.

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
    "attributes": {
        "key": "iana.org/language_tag",
        "value": "en"
    },
    "data":  "Base64 Encoded String"
}  
,{
    "attributes": {
        "key": "iana.org/language_tag",
        "value": "en"
    },

    "data":  "Base64 Encoded String"
}  

  ]
}
```

For the example above, there are two base64 encoded strings being sent in one request. My question is, what is the maximum amount of data I which can be passed in one request? I've tried looking through the API Reference but I'm not able to find anything which answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is on the [quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#other_limits): A publish request must be no larger than 10MB and contain no more than 1,000 messages.